# I have added maven for admob on the gradle but why this error comes

Tags: android, android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

i want to add admob ads on my app i have added dependencies you can check above and i have add maven on the gradle but why this error comes

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
```

}

but my error comes on this line below
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

and the error is

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

why this error comes i dont know

Answer (score 0):

customtabs libs is using the version of support library 26.1.0 which is less than 28.0.0-alpa1.

All your libraries should be using the same version of the support libraries either 28.0.0-alpha1 or 26.1.0. Can you change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`